# Rise of Skywalker like The Highlander?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

At the end of *The Rise of Skywalker* the characters,

> Palpatine and Rey, seem to imply they have taken on the powers of all the dead Sith and Jedi, respectively.  This strikes me as very much like *The Highlander* in that they gain the powers of the fallen.

However, is this really what was implied by their statements like, "I am all the Jedi..."?

That is, do they really adopt the powers of the fallen?  Or was this just meant as an inspirational metaphor?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Sci-Fi stackexchange! Good first question! I've done a little tidying, but if you need anything else don't hesitate to comment. Also please take the [tour], and have a look at the [help].

Comment: She took on their powers for a few moments. Long enough to kill Palpie

Comment: @Valorum I thought it was more that the Jedi _loaned_ her their power briefly, as distinct from her winning their power (permanently) like how power was inherited in *Highlander*.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - It seems I am having a difficult time discerning what is required of a quality question.  SciFi/Fantasy are, for me, purely about opinion, speculation, and personal interpretation of words or movies.  I can see several questions in the "Related" column to the right that look virtually no different than mine yet I have two downvotes already.  For instance, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/225020/136731 is 100% hypothetical and opinion based, is it not?  What am I missing?  (I seem to do better in the Physics SE)

Comment: I suspect that your downvotes are coming because your question (and especially the title) are conflating two entirely separate fictional universes.

Comment: @valorum the question is drawing a parallel, but they doesn't mean they're being conflated.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - What I mean is that the Highlander reference is almost entirely unneeded. "***Does Rey keep the powers of all of the Jedi?***" would be sufficient.

Comment: @Valorum it's a fine shorthand, and I got the meaning straight away, as did you it seems from your answer?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Indeed. And I didn't downvote it for precisely that reason, that I understand the question because I'm familiar with both properties. OP was, however, asking why others might have downvoted it.

Comment: @Valorum - Ah that is a fair point.  I asked it this way because I was wondering if someone knew whether this was a semi-intentional plot point by the writers or just happenstance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rey is described in the [official novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_Expanded_Edition) as being a '*conduit*' for the power of the (former) Jedi Order rather than possessing their power to herself. After the fight is over, there's no good evidence that she still has this vast Force power, merely returning to that of a single Jedi.

> Presences filled her awareness, some recent, some ancient, some still
> anchored to the living in a strange way. Rey didn’t understand. But
> she accepted.
>
> Alone, never have you been.
>
> Every Jedi who ever lived, lives in you.
>
> The Force surrounds you.
>
> Let it guide you.
>
> As it guided us.
>
> Palpatine had wanted Rey for himself. But she chose to be their
> conduit. Their vessel. She was a Jedi.
>
> Rey moved an arm. Then a shoulder. She let the voices surround her,
> fill her, strengthen her. She turned over, placed a palm to the
> ground, pushed up.
>
> We stand behind you.
>
> Rise in the Force.

Later on when we see her, she's back to being ordinary old Jedi Rey. She can still commune with Force ghosts, but she's not filled with their voices and powers.

> So many memories here. She could feel them—yearning, loss, worry,
> desperation, love—and not just Luke’s. Two generations of Skywalkers
> had visited this place.
>
> A cavelike entrance in the wall drew her forward. As she passed into
> shadow and her eyes adjusted, she noted a long dining table, covered
> with dust. She ran a finger through the dust, tracing a line of soft
> blue. Luke had dined here. And also—she reached out, sensing—Anakin?